# Convergence of Taylor series of $\sqrt{1-x}$

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Concerning $$\sqrt{1-x} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left[\prod_{j=1}^k \left(\frac{j-1-\frac{1}{2}}{j}\right)\right]x^k$$

the Taylor series about $x=0$. For $|x|< 1$ this series converges uniformly.

It appears, I read here http://www.math.purdue.edu/~zhang24/StoneWeierstrass.pdf
that the series converges uniformly for $x\in [0,1]$

So how can we show this? We need to know then also that it converges for $x=1$, and then we need to see how these coefficients of $x^k$ must be summable, i guess..
I just don't see how?

Comment: Where does it say that?

Comment: In any case, check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series#Proof for a proof of convergence at 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The terms

$$a_k = (-1)^k\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{k} = \prod_{j=1}^k \frac{j-1-\frac{1}{2}}{j}$$

satisfy

$$\left\lvert \frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\right\rvert = \frac{(k+1)-1-\frac{1}{2}}{k+1} = 1 - \frac{\frac{3}{2}}{k+1}.$$

By [Raabe's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#Raabe.27s_test), the sum is absolutely convergent for $\lvert x\rvert = 1$.

The uniform convergence for $\lvert x\rvert \leqslant 1$ then follows, since

$$\left\lvert \sum_{k=N}^\infty (-1)^k\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{k}x^k\right\rvert \leqslant \sum_{k=N}^\infty \left\lvert \binom{\frac{1}{2}}{k}\right\rvert$$

for all $\lvert x\rvert \leqslant 1$.