Polynomials with only even terms are dense in the set of polynomials in $[0,1]$ with sup norm.
Let ${\cal P}$ set of all polynomials on one variable in $[0,1]$. It can be equipped with the supremum norm to obtain a normed space. Consider ${\cal Q}= \{a_0 + a_2x^2+a_4x^4+\dots a_{2k}x^{2k}: a_j\in \mathbb{R}, k \in \mathbb{N}  \}$. That is, ${\cal Q}$ is the set of all polynomials with odd terms equal to zero.
Given $p\in {\cal P}$, is it possible to explicitly construct a sequence in ${\cal Q}$ that converges to $p$ with the supremum norm? I'd like to prove that ${\cal P}$ is dense in ${\cal P}$ with the supremum norm without using theorems as Muntz theorem that I did not previously prove.

Perhaps consider defining an even polynomial in the 'obvious' way on $[-1,1]$?

@copper.hat Ok, I can define $r(x) = p(x)$ if $x\in [-1,0)$. So now I have an even polynomial in $[-1,1]$.

See below. ${}{}$

Another hack:
Extend $p$ to $[-1,0)$ by defining $p(x) = p(-x)$, then $p$ is even on $[-1,1]$. Let $q_n$ be a sequence of polynomials that converges uniformly on [$-1,1]$ to the extended $p$. Note that if we let $\tilde{q}_n(x) = q_n(-x)$ we have $\|p-q_n\|_\infty = \|p-\tilde{q}_n\|_\infty$, and since the norm is convex, we see that, with $p_n = {1 \over 2}(q_n+\tilde{q}_n)$ we have
$\|p-p_n\|_\infty \le \|p-q_n\|_\infty$, so $p_n$ converges uniformly to $p$ as well. Note that $p_n$ is even.

Hope, the following construction is explicit enough.
At first pick any method that suites you to approximate the function $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ on $[0,1]$ uniformly by polynomials (e.g., partial sums of Taylor series). Let $p_n(x)$ be any sequence of polynomials converging uniformly to $f$ on $[0,1]$. Now, clearly, $p_n(x^2)$ converges uniformly to $f(x^2) \equiv x$.
Finally, let $p(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^d a_k x^k$. Then each term $a_k x^k$ can be easily approximated by the sequence $a_k (p_n(x^2))^k$. So, the sequence $\sum_{k = 0}^d a_k (p_n(x^2))^k$ converges to $p$.

I meant Taylor series with center at $x = 1$ and it is known to converge uniformly on $[0,1]$. See, e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/863526/convergence-of-taylor-series-of-sqrt1-x @operatorerror

In a similar manner you could also approximate $x \mapsto f(\sqrt{x})$. Then the polynomials $x \mapsto p(x^2)$ will converge to $f$.

For $p(x)\in\mathcal{P}$ we have $$p(x)=p_1(x^2)+xp_2(x^2)$$ for some polynomials $p_1$ and $p_2.$ Since  $p_1(x^2),p_2(x^2)\in \mathcal{Q},$ it suffices to focus on $x.$  The function $\sqrt{t}$ is the uniform limit of a sequence of polynomials $r_n(t).$ Then $r_n(x^2)\rightrightarrows x,$ which implies $$p_1(x^2)+r_n(x^2)p_2(x^2)\rightrightarrows p(x)$$
